# Setting a broken git branch to a detached head

Tags: git

After a power loss during a commit, one of the branches in my git repository got corrupted.  I did `git fsck --full` and deleted all the empty object files until `fsck` gave me:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (894584/894584), done.
error: refs/heads/git-annex does not point to a valid object!
Checking connectivity: 862549, done.
```

I then used `git fsck --lost-found` to find my last good dangling commit on the `git-annex` branch.  I checked it out.

I want this to be my replacement `git-annex` HEAD.  I tried `git checkout -b git-annex` but got that the branch already exists.  So I tried `git branch -d git-annex` but got `error: Couldn't look up commit object for 'refs/heads/git-annex'`.

How can I get rid of the broken `git-annex` branch in order to set it to the commit I want?  I have already tried just removing `.git/refs/heads/git-annex` but that doesn't work.  Thanks.

Comment: Use `-B` when you want to abandon the old branch tip, e.g. `git checkout -B git-annex 1a2b3cd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me (after "cheating" to insert a broken branch, and seeing the same error when trying to delete it):

```
git branch -f broked HEAD  # or some other valid point
git branch -d broked
```

The second command gripes as it deletes the broken ref from .git/packed-refs (which is where I assume it must be if removing .git/refs/heads/git-annex was unhelpful).  (But the branch name "git-annex" makes me wonder if you're using [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/), as in, the thing that stores large files outside the repo.  I have not used that myself and am not sure if this changes anything.)

Comment: Actually all I needed was the first command, which I could use to set `git-annex` to the dangling commit.  Now `git fsck` is clean.  Thanks for that.

I am indeed using git-annex, but am fairly sure that in this case this doesn't change anything.